# struct.Struct inheritance with Python 3.12.0

Tags: python, inheritance, struct

Recently upgraded my virtual env to Python 3.12.0. Run into a strange bug (?) that didn't exist with Python 3.11.5.

```py
import struct


class MyStruct(struct.Struct):

    format_chars = {
        "char": "c",
        "uint8_t": "B",
        "uint16_t": "H",
        "float": "f",
        "uint32_t": "I",
    }   
    
    def __init__(self, structure: dict[str, str]):
        self.structure = structure
        fmt = self._get_fmt_str()
        super().__init__(fmt)

    def _get_fmt_str(self) -> str:
        fmt = "".join(
            self.format_chars.get(v, v) for v in self.structure.values()
        )
        return f"<{fmt}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    structure = {"uint8_t": "B"}
    my_struct = MyStruct(structure)
    assert my_struct.size == 1, "sizes not equal"
```

```py
(struct-testing-py) .\struct-testing-py>python my_struct.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\my_struct.py", line 28, in <module>
    my_struct = MyStruct(structure)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Struct() argument 1 must be a str or bytes object, not dict
```

I created a new virtual env with `3.11.5` and the code worked fine.

Also created a fresh new virtual env with `3.12.0` and it still failed.

Comment: I have the same error with struct.Struct inheritance in Python 3.12.0 in new Fedora 39 installation. I have opened a bug report https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/112358

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure But I think Your problem is due to 3.12. It is very new and due to this it can cause problems so stick to 3.11 and if I solved your problem mark this as the answer :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).